# Bower package css not added to vendor.css

Tags: gulp, bower, yeoman-generator-angular, wiredep

I'm using this yeoman generator (https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) for my project.  And have added a couple of bower libraries, namely, videojs, ngDialog.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the css files included in these libraries aren't being packaged up into the vendor.css file like the rest of the packages are.  I know that that the generator uses wiredep, but I'm afraid I don't know enough about it to find out what went wrong.

Basically, when I go to view source, I see that there are style includes underneath the vendor.css style include, eg.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.css">
```

Also notice how it is included using "../".  This would break if I'm in an HTML file that is in a directory other than the root.

Any pointers?

Thanks.
John.

Comment: Can you clarify your building process step by step? I've tried to include ngDialog through bower and rerun `gulp build` in command line, it seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you don't have to worry about the building process, the `gulpfile` provided by `gulp-angular` is well configured for you future including bower components.

Once you run `bower install your_component`, be sure to run `gulp build` again in command line, it will then include the needed styles to your index.html.

If you would like to know more about the underlying process with that, you may check `yourapp/src/index.html` from line 12 to line 20 to get a sense of it. For how wiredep works for your bower components, the [official document](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @kavare.  I've tried running `gulp build` after running `bower install your_component`.  However, the components' css is still being included separately instead of being dumped inside the vendor.css file.  What's interesting is, there's definitely something inside vendor.css from bootstrap and bootstrap only.

Is there something that I can post here to help work out what's wrong?
Thanks.